# When i put file.FullName(which is not null i debugged) into an string array some are null and some are not

Tags: c#, forms, file, picturebox, getfiles

So let's say as example i have the image path which is "D:\..." anything.
file.FullName is this path, but sometimes when i put that path into the array
the element is null but i have no idea why.

Let's say i have 100 pictures in the folder then 10 percent of their names are null
in the array but i checked in debuggin file.FullName is never null.

Someone has an idea why this happens?
Or did i overlook something?

```
            int z = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo file in Variables.dir.GetFiles())
            {
                try
                {
                    this.myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                    names[z] = file.FullName;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
                }
                z++;
            }
```

Comment: I would try moving `z++;` to within the `try{}` instead of outside of the `catch{}` . Otherwise, even when it's not a file you want, `name[z]` is still going to increment

Comment: that worked thanks, but i only have images in this folder so why does if find files that arent images?

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing your directory location . It's possible there's hidden files, it's looking at a different location when running outside of debug mode, several other reasons. If my suggestion worked for you, I'll add an answer for you to accept!

Comment: ye you can do that

Comment: Side note: you probably wanted to use `List` and `.Add` elements to it rather than re-implement "growing array"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, even when erroring, is still incrementing `z`. Move `z` to within `try{}` instead of outside the `catch{}` / `finally{}` . This will cause `z` to only increment when the program finds only files that it is looking for / that match your criteria (i.e Image files).

```
        int z = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in Variables.dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                this.myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                names[z] = file.FullName;
                z++;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }
```

Your program could be finding hidden files or others when not looking in a debugged file path. Multiple reasons for your code to `catch{}`, but not certain without adding in:

```
try{ ... }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file: \n" + ex); 
}
```

in order to at least get the proper error to further debug

Answer (score 2):

Either change the order of your lines:

`this.myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));`

and

`names[z] = file.FullName;`

so that names[z] gets assigned the filename BEFORE the exception sends you to the `catch` block due to issues loading the image file.

Or consider adding a `finally{ names[z] = file.FullName; }` block so that the names array always gets the filename even when there is an exception.

You'll wind up with a different number of items in your ImageList as some files will never get added, but your list of filenames will at least be complete